# Struggling with no sound, on Lenovo Legion 7 Pro, with Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, lenovo, soundcard, audio-jack

I have Legion 7 Pro, which contains Realtek ALC3306 chipset.
I installed Ubuntu 23.10 with kernel 6.5.0-13.
Tried available methods on internet to solve it. But didn't find any working solution.

My sound system not working, unable to hear any audio. Also, tried multiple kernels using mainline, but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks, for any help.

please, let me know, if there is any other thread, or any other active community.
[image]

Comment: I just got the Yoga Slim 7 14APU8 and running Ubuntu 23.10. Same audio chipset. I do have audio but very bad quality, very soft and "canny". Als tried different kernels, on 6.6.7 now, doesn't fix it. Tried messing around with"Pulse Audio Volume Control" and alsamixer, no result.

Comment: Related: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213159

Comment: FYI: nahimic is the only stack holder for drivers, Coz last time when I updated nahimic on windows, even then windows was unable to pop the sound & was getting some noise on pc start. Had to reinstall windows. Maybe only nahimic have driver for this device.